# How to convert an array to a hash with specified common values

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array: `arr = [:a, :b, :c]`

I want a hash where each of the above values is a key with an empty hash as its value: `hsh = {a: {}, b: {}, c: {}}`

What's the most succinct way of doing that (and are there performance tradeoffs)?

Here is my current solution:

```
arr.inject({}) do |hash, entry|
  hash[entry] = {}
  hash
end
```

Comment: The title is a bit unclear, because of the reference to "default values". If you simply want to create a hash whose keys are contained in a given array and whose values are empty hashes, that has nothing to do with "default" values. On the other hand, you do need default values if, once you have `hsh = {a: {}, b: {}, c: {}}`, you execute `hsh.delete(:a); hsh[:a]` and expect the result to be `{}` rather than `nil`. A fine point, but one the needs clarification.

Comment: Ah yes I can see why it'd be unclear. The reason I used the phrasing  'default values' was because the choice of empty hashes as the values was a special case -- the general case includes using empty arrays, zeros, etc. as the values, which to me were types of 'default' (rather than idiosyncratically assigned) values.  What phrasing do you think would be better?

Comment: Maybe, "How to convert an array to a hash with specified common values".  You don't need "most succinct way"; that's the name of the game at SO.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer, assuming at least one was helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways, e.g.:

```
arr.zip([{}] * arr.size).to_h
```

or (the latter, thx @Stefan, is not probably what you wanted, since it will share one hash for all keys):

```
arr.product([{}]).to_h
```

Comment: requires recent ruby, though :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Indeed, `2.0` is not very recent already, though :)

Comment: I really like the `product` one. Nice ;)

Comment: The `product` example will use the same hash instance for each pair, probably not what the OP wants :-)

Comment: @Stefan Yes, my mistake, updated answer with a note.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the modification of `Hash[arr.zip([{}] * arr.size)]` would make this backwards compatible without issue.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) instead of `inject` to avoid the return value:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |k, h| h[k] = {} }
#=> {:a=>{}, :b=>{}, :c=>{}}
```

<sup><sub>There's a shorter way hidden in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31681135/revisions), but Cary does not recommend it ;-)</sub></sup>

Comment: My advice: delete the last three lines.

Comment: My advice: delete the last four lines. :-) (Never offer an alternative to the best solution--it just weakens your answer.)

Comment: Did you use [Enumerable#tinyfy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235927/ruby-style-for-displaying-long-arrays)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland it gets even smaller if you combine `sup` and `sub`

Comment: Good to know. In fact, it appears you can make the text arbitrarily small. If interested, see the revision history to my answer at the link. I just did an edit.

Answer (score 3):

- + Expresses exactly what you wanted.
- + Doesn't create multiple pairs that get merged into one hash.
- + Lazy - will be ready for use instantly / wont waste memory for unused keys.
- - Lazy - if `arr` is modified the initially available keys will also be modified if you haven't already accessed them.
- - Does linear search in the array each time you want to access a new key.

  ```
  Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {} if arr.include? key }
  ```

Comment: Probably the best solution.

Comment: I just ran this in `pry`, it returned an empty hash not a hash of hashes with keys from `arr` matched to empty hashes. What am I missing?

Comment: @Beartech, as I said, it is lazy. Once you access a key you will get either an empty hash or `nil` depending on if the key was in the array.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Very interesting solution.

Comment: This may be a good way of doing it (I especially like the conditional clause), but the OP was specific that the desired hash should be `h = {a: {}, b: {}, c: {}}` (not an empty hash). What if, immediately after creating the hash, the OP wants to execute `h.keys`?

Comment: @mudasobwa, I disagree, for reasons given in my comment above. Your solution is better.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, as I said - the solution is lazy with all of its implications. :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland it could be performed this way `h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {} if arr.include? key }; h.values_at(*arr)` which will immediately create these keys inside `h` but I agree it lacks a certain appeal.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of techniques I came up with

**Technique 1**

```
p Hash[arr.dup.fill{ |i| [arr[i], {}]}] # preserves original arr, works on copy (dup)
p Hash[arr.fill{ |i| [arr[i], {}]}] # mutates original arr
```

**Technique 2**

```
arr = [:a, :b, :c]
p Hash[arr.zip(Array.new(arr.length) { |i| i = {}})]
```

**Technique 3** - this is a variant of technique 2, uses `to_h` method available in Ruby 2.1

```
p  [:a, :b, :c].instance_eval { self.zip(Array.new(self.length) {|i| i = {}})}.to_h
```

All the above techniques will produce desired output of

```
{:a=>{}, :b=>{}, :c=>{}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is with `each`:

```
hsh = {}
arr.each {|x| hsh[x] = {}}
```

Comment: This returns an array of hashes, not the same.

Comment: Edited to produce a hash instead of an array.

Comment: Yes, it became unneeded once it became clear they wanted a hash of hashes instead of an array. Change to each.